# how to differentiate ng-grid event with two grids in single page

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have two *ng-grid* in page, and I want to use two corresponding `ngGridEventEndCellEdit` event:

```
 <div id="grid1" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions1"></div>
 <div id="grid2" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions2"></div>

function HomeCtrl($scope, $http) {
 $scope.columns = [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: false }, { field: 'age', displayName: 'Age', enableCellEdit: false }];        

 $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    data: 'myData', enablePinning: true, enableCellEdit: true, enableRowSelection: false,
    columnDefs: 'columns'
 };

 $scope.columns2 = [{ field: 'name1', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: false }, { field: 'Age1', displayName: 'Age', enableCellEdit: false }];        

 $scope.gridOptions2 = {
    data: 'myData2', enablePinning: true, enableCellEdit: true, enableRowSelection: false,
    columnDefs: 'columns2'
 };
 $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

$scope.myData2 = [{name1: "Moroni", age1: 50},
                         {name1: "Tiancum", age1: 43},
                         {name1: "Jacob", age1: 27},
                         {name1: "Nephi", age1: 29},
                         {name1: "Enos", age1: 34}];
}
```

There are two grids, and I want two different event of `ngGridEventEndCellEdit` on cell edit based on grid id. How can i do that ?

```
//for  grid1
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {

};

//for  grid2
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {

};
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular event, one way we could do it is:

```
$scope.gridOptions1 = {
   //options for grid 1
}

$scope.gridOptions2 = {
   //options for grid 2
}

$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(event) {
   switch(event.targetScope.gridId) {
      case $scope.gridOptions1.$gridScope.gridId:
         //handle the event for grid 1
         break;
      case $scope.gridOptions2.$gridScope.gridId:
         //handle the event for grid 2
         break;
   }
});
```